# How do I access a method from a custom made class?

Tags: javascript, class, methods

I have a class defined as follows:

```
export default class MyClass {

    myMethod(code){
        console.log("The code is" + code)
    }
}
```

How can I access it from my main class? In the main class I have the following  lines of code:

```
import MC from './MyClass'

...

MC.myMethod("987");
```

The error I am getting is:

```
undefined is not a function (evaluating '_MyClass2.default.myMethod("987")'
```

What am I doing wrong? Also, what do the `_`, `2`, and `default` mean in the error message next to my class name?

Comment: Is that javascript or Eiffel or smalltalk,...? :)

Comment: @BitTickler it's an es6 javascript class

Answer (score 2):

That's because you've created an instance method, so you have two options. Either create an instance of that class:

```
var c = new MyClass();

c.myMethod();
```

Or set that as a [`static`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static) method:

```
static myMethod(code) {
  // ...
}
```

Another way is to [`export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) the functions directly:

```
export myMethod(code) {
  // ...
end
```

Comment: Thank you. Would this mean that most of the 3rd party modules that I use (such as react-native-fs) would use the static method approach as I don't have to create an instance of the class?

Comment: Conventional JavaScript objects (non-`class`) just have methods you can call, they don't need to be instantiated because they're already in their final form. If you're using ES6 classes you need to declare them `static`. If you're not intending to actually create instances of your class, you're just using it as a container, consider using [`export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) instead on whatever functions or values you're trying to pass over.

Answer (score 1):

When declaring a JS Es6 class, remember that its method members are bound to each instance of the class or bound to the class itself if you used the *static* keyword :

```
class MyClass {

     myMethod() {

         // each object created with the *new* keyword will have this method:
         // const o = new MyClass();
         // typeof o.myMethod === "function" will return true 
     }

}

class MyClass {

     static myMethod() {

         // typeof MyClass.myMethod === "function" will return true 

     }

}
```

Depending of its declaration, when invoked its lexical context *this* will either be bound to the instance (first case) or the class itself (2nd form).

You should also now that all instance methods (like the second case) are put inside the prototype property of you class. So you have :

```
class MyClass () {

    myMethod() {} 

}

(typeof MyClass.protototype.myMethod === "function") // true

const o = new MyClass()

(o.myMethod === MyClass.prototype.myMethod); // true
```

For static methods (or class methods) the method is directly attached to the class object.

The error you see in your case is caused because your method was not declared with the static keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare an object of your class before start calling its methods just like in any other programming languages.

```
export class MyClass {

    public myMethod(code){
        console.log("The code is" + code)
    }
}
```

Then import it wherever you want to use

```
import MC from './MyClass'
```

Create an object from your import and call the method

```
var mc = new MC();
mc.myMethod("987");
```